# Installing PhoneGap from NPM Fails

Tags: node.js, cordova, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install PhoneGap from NPM, but it is failing on install - I have set the registry again as another post suggested but it still fails.

Any help would be great!

```
js@jspi ~ $ sudo npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
js@jspi ~ $ sudo npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: phonegap
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/js/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.10.25+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /home/js
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: phonegap
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/js/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

NPM Version - 1.1.4
Node Version:

```
js@jspi ~ $ sudo nodejs --version
v0.6.19
```

OS Details:

```
js@jspi ~ $ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a later version of Node?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [`package.json`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/blob/master/package.json#L26) file of PhoneGap on the GitHub repository, you'll see these lines:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.10.0"
}
```

The line means that the package requires at least Node.js version `0.10.0` to run/install. Therefore, to fix your problem, update to the latest version of Node or at least version `0.10.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force the install by adding -f :

```
sudo npm install -gf phonegap
```